# How critical is it to use the correct wire colors within the same electrical outlet?

Tags: receptacle, code-compliance, grounding, wire

I am replacing "razor only" receptacles to GFCI. The outlet contains a LINE cable (black, white, bare copper). The previous receptacle of course did not use three prongs, so the ground was just secured to the outlet box's grounding terminal (screw).

To install the GFCI according to the instructions, I need two new pieces of wire for the ground pigtail: one to the grounding terminal, and one to the receptacle's ground. See diagram below.

**My small problem** is that I don't have green or bare copper wire. I have suitable 6" 14 AWG wire scraps from the old receptacle, but they are white or black.

- Would it be terrible if I used the wrong colors to make the pigtail? Electrically of course there's no problem. Potential confusion is the only issue I can see, but since it would all be in the same outlet box, maybe that's less of a problem?
- It also occurred to me to strip the black/white insulation and thus have bare copper, but it is stranded (all the wires from LINE are solid), so that seems like a bit of a mess. Is that even ok to do?

[image: grounding instructions]

Comment: You can strip the wire if it's being used for ground. Or wrap it in green electrical tape.

Comment: Can't find anything saying bare stranded wire is a problem. I've installed light fixtures that include a bare stranded ground wire.

Comment: @Nate Wouldn't a 6" bare stranded wire get messy? I'm not sure how many strands there are but it's a lot, as in probably dozens.

Comment: @adatum -- it's going to be either 7 or 19 strands, not "dozens" unless it's fine-stranded wire, which isn't generally used for mains work

Comment: It will be twisted on one end by a wire nut, and clamped to a screw terminal at the other end, and only be a few inches long. I wouldn't worry about it being messy. You can always wrap some electrical tape around it if you find it too messy to work with. Or you can always run to the hardware store for some green #12 THHN, it's less than 10¢ a foot here

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It's definitely more than 7 strands. I'd be surprised if it's 19 but I could be wrong. I'm curious now, so I might count them later. I counted 16 strands on what I'm guessing is 18 AWG and that looks far less dense, though those wires are probably thinner too.

Comment: @Nate It's not an issue of cost, but rather the hassle and a preference to use what I already have. Electrical tape might make things messier, and I think I have only black and yellow tape. Perhaps I'll try the bare wire and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay. If you wind up using the tape, I'd probably go for the yellow not the black. I always read black and red as "hot".

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel 41 strands. I counted on two different wires segments to be sure. The strand diameter seems the same as a 16 strand wire which I think is 18 AWG. I believe the 41 strand is 14 AWG. It could make sense according to this chart: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/70228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is "quite critical":  Grounds must be green, yellow/green or bare.  Neutrals must be white or gray.  All others are hot.

Binding stranded wire to a screw terminal is tricky. Not impossible but tricky.  I like to "super-twist it" by gripping  the wire in a hole intended to shear off bolts, which keeps it circular.  You have to have just the right touch to clamp the wire enough to hold it without shearing it.

Because of the difficulty for a novice to attach stranded wire to a screw terminal, I would advise either going to the shop and getting some solid #12 wire, or, you can use round crimp terminals for the ground screw on the junction box (not on a receptacle).

If you have wire whose insulation is not green or yellow-green, there are two ways to mark it as a ground.

- Strip all the insulation off. Optional: wrap it with green tape, which will solve the birdcaging issue if the supertwist doesn't.
- Don't strip the insulation off and totally obscure it with green tape. *However this violates Code*.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I did notice that half of the strands tended to "squish" out from under the screw head when I tried it previously. Is the pigtail in the instructions necessary? eg. would it be ok to keep LINE's solid ground wire at the screw terminal and add another wire from the screw terminal to the receptacle's ground? Exploring this left me lacking confidence in how securely the screw could hold more than one wire (especially with the addition of the stranded one), not to mention questions of Code.

Comment: @adatum putting more than one wire on a screw is absolutely forbidden anyway.  Unless you use round crimp terminals, but you quickly find you would need to get 5 fingers and 3 thumbs inside the hole while also holding a screwdriver :)

Comment: @Harper -- wiring device screws aren't rated for use with ring or spade terminals anyway...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I assume adaturn is talking about the ground screw in the back of the box.   Yes, agreed, on a receptacle that won't do.

Comment: Yes, I meant the ground screw in the box. "absolutely forbidden".. good to know, and even better to know the reasons. I think I have some solid copper wire (with grey insulation) but I'll need to check the size. As for crimp terminals what do I need to know? I might have some lying around but I know nothing of types and sizes and I'm not looking to create fire hazards.

Comment: @adatum -- if you can't find a suitable wire for pigtailing, you can get premade 12AWG grounding pigtails (screw, lug, and wire) at just about any home-improvement store these days

Comment: @adatum try it and you'll see, the two wires end up squishing all over the place and only having good contact on a couple of points.  You know a proper 1-wire connection is a J-hook that goes clear round the screw... There's no room for another wire unless you stack them, and that's what doesn't work.

Comment: @Harper What do you think of using solid 14 AWG wire to the ground screw and stranded wire to the receptacle, resulting in a 2 solid, 1 stranded (3 wire) connection? Also, do you think 41 strand 14 AWG wire would be fine without its insulation? I just realized the grey insulated solid wire scrap was left by a telecom technician who used it for ground as is... not stripped or relabelled with tape. But its purpose is obvious as it connects to the thick bare copper ground of an electrical panel.

Comment: Well, Code has trouble arguing with bare wire for ground, so many inappropriate kinds of insulation actually work for ground if you strip it off. The ruling questions are a) is it large enough, 20A breaker needs #12; and b) can you terminate it competently at the device.  Wire-nutting solid into stranded is definitely not a problem but like any wire-nutting, requires good technique,

Comment: @Harper The receptacle has nice screws and clamps for all terminations including ground (bottom screw in inset "Back Wire" image in the diagram above), so that part seems easy. I think the main LINE is #14 (solid) and the #14 stranded wires I salvaged are from the previous razor-only receptacle (the part before the transformer), which makes me think (and hope) it's a 15A circuit. But the glass plug fuse I removed from the electrical box for this circuit has "25" printed on it, for 25A ?? That has me confused and a bit worried. References for good wire-nutting technique appreciated.

Comment: In the end I found some #14 solid copper wire scraps and used two 6" bare pieces to make the ground connections as in the instructions. I also replaced the circuit's fuse with a 15A one.